# How to get a specific string between characters?

Tags: java, android

For example:

```
result={"id":"8550","iduser":1,"name":"John"}
```

Display only the number front of iduser only the number 1 mean that I want to keep or store inside temporary value the value of iduser?

I tried this:

```
String display = result.substring(result.indexOf("iduser:") + 1, result.indexOf(","));
```

but is this method bad? Anyone any idea?

Comment: This looks like JSON, so why not simply use proper parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). Would be something like:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    int iduser = jsonObject.getInt("iduser");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("ErrorOn:iduser", e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a JSON object, so you have a few options here.

You can either trim off the beginning `result=` and parse it as JSON, then read the `iduser` value.

Or, you can use regex to match the specific value for `iduser`

> \"iduser\":([0-9]+)[,}]

Answer (score 0):

The string you are working with appears to be JSON, so it is always better to use a JSON Parser library rather than substring operation.